how to create cluster aks hci with terraform?
I try to create cluster aks hci (aks hybrid) with terraform i use this provisioner "local-exec"
this is my main.tf
resource "null_resource" "test_terraform" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "New-AksHciCluster -name ${var.cluster_name} -nodePoolName ${var.nodepool_name} -nodeCount ${var.node_count} -osType ${var.os_type} && Connect-AzAccount && Enable-AksHciArcConnection -name ${var.cluster_name}"
  }
}

I got this problem:

Error running command 'New-AksHciCluster -name test-terraform -nodePoolName node1 -nodeCount 1 -osType Linux && Connect-AzAccount &&
│ Enable-AksHciArcConnection -name test-terraform': exit status 1. Output: 'New-AksHciCluster' n’est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
│ ou externe, un programme exécutable ou un fichier de commandes.

command New-AksHciCluster execute normally in my powershell
any solution or there is any another solution to create aks hybrid locale in my infrastructure
